# Can "plunge" be used for a "horizontal dive"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

You often *plunge* into the sea or *plunge* you hands into your pockets.

Can the word be used to describe a "horizontal immersion"?

Example sentence:

> She opened the door and **plunged** into the blinding sun.

If not, what's a more appropriate word?

Comment: You could say "she threw herself" -- but "plunged" could work.

Comment: "Plunge" just means to enter quickly and forcibly or to descend suddenly.  Orientation has nothing to do with it, and immersion could be something that happens afterwards.  Plunging into the sunshine would describe moving quickly into the sunshine.

Comment: I'd see it as metaphorical but acceptable. What's "more appropriate" depends on what you're writing. This reads like a sentence from a story (whether a novel or a shorter form). If that's what you're writing, no problem. If it's a police report, maybe it's not the right verb.

Comment: @alex Sure: "She *plunged* the knife into his chest."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly acceptable, but you might want to consider the "literal baggage," for lack of a better word, that the figurative term carries with it.

Take the OED literal definition that this derives from:

> To thrust, throw, or drop into or in a liquid, penetrable substance, deep pit, container, etc.; to immerse, to submerge.

In any case that you use the word "plunge," readers will associate it with the literal meaning to derive its figurative meaning.  If you want to invoke feelings of falling deep into something, then it's appropriate.  Just be aware that the use **ordinarily** refers to falling or pushing *in a downward direction*.

Answer (score 5):

The OED's first meaning of ***plunge*** involves transitively thrusting, throwing or dropping something (or oneself) into a liquid - from the French ***plonger*** - *to jump into water, to submerge, or sink*

However, sense 4 (intransitive) of the verb covers precisely the circumstance you relate:

> 4. intr. To move or travel forth, on, etc., rapidly, abruptly, or recklessly; to move with a rush or sudden impulse into or out of; to
>      hurtle, career. Also fig. 1726   W. Broome in Pope et al. tr. Homer
>      Odyssey V. xxiii. 256   He views the strand, And plunging forth with
>      transport grasps the land.
>
> 1806   T. Jefferson Let. 5 July in Writings (1984) 1165   If the
>   executive is to keep all other information to himself, and the House
>   to plunge on in the dark, it becomes a government of chance and not of
>   design.
>
> 1834   L. Ritchie Wanderings by Seine 110   We..plunged into the high
>   road leading to Duclair.
>
> 1885   Manch. Examiner 22 Jan. 5/2   Under a well-organised fire from
>   the works, the Arabs plunged forth upon the square.
>
> 1891   C. Graves Field of Tares iv. vi. 241   The Norwich Express,
>   plunging out of Liverpool Street Station.
>
> a1902   F. Norris Pit (1903) x. 400   She had committed herself now;
>   recklessly she plunged on.
>
> 1954   Times Lit. Suppl. 12 Nov. 714/4   As the Age of Reason plunged
>   towards revolution, Juvenal was carried like a banner in the van of
>   the attack.
>
> 1990   A. Stevens On Jung ii. 18   The dreamer might see a train,
>   carrying him home, plunging in and out of a series of tunnels.
>
> 2004   Derby Evening Tel. (Nexis) 16 Mar. 6   If the Germans had
>   captured crossings over the Trent, they could have plunged in any
>   direction.

Comment: sunlight seems to be treated like a liquid in literature, "bathed in sunlight", "drenched in sunlight", "showering sunlight", etc.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all definitions of Plunging seem to imply that it's a word describing vertical descent.
[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/plunge) thesaurus includes the following words as related:

> dip, immersion, submersion; fall, plump, slip, spill, stumble, tumble; descent, drop; belly flop, header, jackknife, swan dive

None of them indicating a horizontal direction.

Also, [Thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/plunging) synonyms imply a vertical nature.

It may be acceptable to use *plunging* in the sentence but you may not get the intended effect on a reader.
Maybe the following will suit better

> She opened the door and **stepped** into the blinding sun.

or

> She opened the door and **charged** into the blinding sun.

Answer (score 2):

"Plunged" is a good word to use, but "sunlight" would be much better then "sun".

Otherwise, you could say "emerged" into the sunlight.

One historical example shows both "plunged" and "emerged" would be good choices:

[Reports of Observations of the Total Eclipse of the Sun, August 7, 1869](https://books.google.com/books?id=c00QPyT2IjMC&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=%22plunged%20into%20%22%20sunlight&source=bl&ots=WqTGBpgo99&sig=zznbtkA2vX7fQjSBLuwgE1CF9vY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT0aK25vvTAhUF6yYKHaqOBnkQ6AEIUTAI#v=onepage&q=%22plunged%20into%20%22%20sunlight&f=false):

> ...observed with what frightful rapidity we were plunged into the dark shadow, and the contrary effect as we emerged into sunlight